# How can I add extra column in datagridview when I fetch data from database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008, datagridview

In my database I have 4 column. I fetch this database value in a datagridview. But I want to add two columns in datagridview. So, I want to make a datagridview with 6 columns. Within this 6 columns 4 columns will filled by database value. How can I do this?

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtusers = new DataTable();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Code,Description,Qnty,Rate from PurchaseTable'", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtusers);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtusers;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Code ";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Description";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Qnty";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Rate";
        con.Close();
```

Here are 4 columns. Code,Description,Qnty,Rate. I want to add two more columns in this datagridview. Amount and Narration. But Amount and Narration columns are not present in PurchaseTable.How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the data for Amount and Narration?   If it is calculated where is it calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want blank columns then create them and insert. If the data is in the database then add a join to your query to retrieve the data.

Adding blank columns

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = dtusers;

DataGridViewColumn amount = new DataGridViewColumn();
amount.HeaderText = "Amount";
amount.Name = "Amount";
dgv.Columns.Insert(0, amount);

DataGridViewColumn narration = new DataGridViewColumn();
narration.HeaderText = "Narration";
narration.Name = "Narration";
dgv.Columns.Insert(0, narration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you already have `dtusers` ..

1. Do **Column adding** to `dtuser` .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx
2. Do looping for all rows in your table to fill your new column
3. Assign the table as dgv datasource .. `dataGridView1.DataSource = dtusers;`

Answer (score 0):

Because your column names are hardcoded,  I think you can create a predefined columns in your datagridview through designer(Click datagridview -> choose Edit Columns).

Create all 6 columns you want.  On the  first four set `DataPropertyName` to name of the column from your query. Last two leave empty.

And remember set `datagridview.AutoGeneratedColumns = false;` before you binding data to datagridview...(somewhere in `form_Load` handler)

After this your code will be:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable dtusers = new DataTable();

    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Code,Description,Qnty,Rate from PurchaseTable'", con))
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtusers);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtusers;
    } 
    con.Close(); 
}
```